# Pre-configuration commands finished with code: 2 when open linux kernel using CLion in macOS

Tags: c, linux, macos

When I using CLion 2022.2.4 open the linux kernel project in macOS Monterey 12.5, the debug output shows error:

```
Pre-configuration commands finished with code: 2
```

and the log output:

```
#
# Kbuild template, feel free to customize.
#
[ -f .config ] || "${MAKE:-make}" defconfig
*** Default configuration is based on 'multi_v7_defconfig'
ld: unknown option: --version
ld: unknown linker
scripts/Kconfig.include:56: Sorry, this linker is not supported.
make[2]: *** [defconfig] Error 1
make[1]: *** [defconfig] Error 2
make: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
Pre-configuration commands finished with code: 2
```

I have already tried this command:

```
➜  linux git:(master) ✗ make menuconfig
  UPD     scripts/kconfig/mconf-cfg
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/mconf.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/checklist.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/inputbox.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/menubox.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/textbox.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/util.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/yesno.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/mconf
ld: unknown option: --version
ld: unknown linker
scripts/Kconfig.include:56: Sorry, this linker is not supported.
make[2]: *** [menuconfig] Error 1
make[1]: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
make: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
```

seems did not work. what should I do to fixed this problem?

Comment: have you fixed this problem?

Comment: No, I did not fixed this problem.@vainman